# Doppler effect naudio

Tags: c#, naudio, pitch-shifting

If I understand correctly, in order to achieve a doppler effect in my wav file I have to alter its frequency. In my project with the Naudio library I have implemented a Isampleprovider and have access to the individual samples(float array). What do I have to do now to achieve the doppler effect(change the frequency?). 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking explicitly for the formula used to determine how much to shift the frequency in order to get a Doppler effect?

Comment: No, I am just asking how to shift the frequency using the Naudio library.